# ФОРМА НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: КОД]

```
<p style="color: crimson; text-align: center;">REGISTRATION FORM</p>
<div id="form">
<form action="" method="post"">
    <input name="login">
    <input name="login" type="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registr">
</form>
</div>

<?php

$DBhost = 'test3.local';
$DBuser = 'root';
$DBpass = '';
$DBname = 'mydb5';
$link = mysqli_connect($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname);
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");


if(!empty($_POST['login']) and !empty($_POST['password']) ) {
    // $login = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['login']);
    // $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $query));
    if(empty($user)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users SET status_id='1', login='$login', password='$passwordHash'";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['status'] = 1;
        echo "excellent";
    } else {
        echo "THIS LOGIN ALREADY TAKEN";
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Для начала ознакомьтесь с https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/191482   ..... а потом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  и отредактируйте вопрос, нормально адекватно как взрослый мыслящий человек, грамотно описав всю проблему

Comment: Под вопросом есть ссылка "Править"

Comment: Теперь читайте как правильно задавать вопросы  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   потому что "не работает ХЭЛП" - ни о чём не говорит

Comment: Не работает. Что делать? Искать ошибку.

Comment: Почему у инпута с `type="password"` `name="login"` так же как и на инпуте для логина?

Comment: Спасибо, хоть кто-то нормально ответил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в инпуте

```
<input type="password" name="login">
```